# Drawing a histogram with ggplot2 when you only have the frequencies

Tags: r, ggplot2

My actual data set is quite large and it takes R some time to process it. So I wrote a little C program to compute the frequency for each possible value. (Say, the possible values in the data set are `0,1,2,3`.) So I have a frequency distribution which (for the sake of presentation) looks like this:

```
0.1 0.4 0.3 0.2
```

If I feed this data to `ggplot2` using `geom_histogram`, I don't get the right histogram. So how can I draw a histogram with the above frequency distribution?

Comment: Might try `geom_col` for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use `stat = 'identity'` within the `geom_bar` call.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3), y = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: echoing @joran's comment above, `geom_col` avoids typing `stat = "identity"`

Comment: Yes, `geom_col` is a very helpful layer.  Note that it was introduced in ggplot2 version 2.2.0.

Comment: The x axis labelling is meaningless

Answer (score 0):

My approach without creating an extra data frame. In the x axis you can find the number of your frequencies

```
 library(ggplot2)
x<-c(0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2)
ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(y=x, x=1:length(x)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```